# processing mouseClicked event not recognise

Tags: java, processing

i tried making a program that will create a visual every time you click, but it didnt work so i stripped down the code to a sample of what didnt work.
at first i thought that the problem was that i didnt have a draw function so processing didnt search for events but when i added the println it still didnt trigger...

can you help me find where i was wrong??

```
void setup(){
 size(500, 400);

 }

void draw(){;}  // listens to events


void mouseClicked(){
  println("d");
}
```

edit1: goldenCucumber told me to get rid of two curly braces, i forgot to delete them (i dont think this is the problem)

edit2:
people asked for the full code:

```
void setup(){
 size(500, 400);
 colorMode(HSB, 100);
 draw_gradients();
 }

void draw_gradients(){
  color c1 = color(random(100), 100, 100);
 color c2 = color(random(100), 100, 30);

 for(int y = 0; y < height;y++){
  float n = map(y, 0, height, 0, 1);
  color newc = lerpColor(c1, c2, n);
  stroke(newc);
  line(0, y, width, y);
  n += 0.01; 
}
}

void draw(){;}  // listens to events


void mouseClicked(){
  println("d");
  draw_gradients();
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. Can you please post the actual code you're running?

Comment: We need a lot more information. Is the listener on a button? on a panel? give us more code

Comment: @Ryan I agree that we need more information, but please note the [tag:processing] tag. This is a Processing event function.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove two unnecessary "}" signs after "size(500, 400);" it works correctly, just tested. I am not sure though if you are aware that println() function only prints text to Processing console in the bottom of the code window. It does not draw it in animation window.

Comment: i forgot to delete this when i deleted most of the code that i deemed not relevent to the question. thx for answering anyways

Comment: and im aware that println prints to console.